# Overriding variance in subtype

Tags: scala, higher-kinded-types

Can someone explain to me why example 1 compiles but example 2 does not?

Example 1:

```
trait Foo[+A]
trait Bar[A] extends Foo[A]
```

Example 2:

```
trait Foo[A[+_]]
trait Bar[A[_]] extends Foo[A]
```

Example 2 does not compile with the following error message: "kinds of the type arguments (A) do not conform to the expected kinds of the type parameters (type A) in trait Foo. A's type parameters do not match type A's expected parameters: type _ (in 
 trait Bar) is invariant, but type _ (in trait Foo) is declared covariant"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Example 1, the **`+A` is not constraint on A**. Any type can be a parameter of Foo. It is a constraint on `Foo`. It means in the interface of `Foo`, `A` can appear only in covariant position (shortly, it may be a method result, but not a method parameter).

Having `Bar` not covariant means that the interface of Bar does not satisfy the same constraint (or at least does not advertise it), so maybe in `Bar`, a method with an `A` parameter was added. This is quite common. For instance there is `collection.Seq[+A]`, and it is extended by `collection.mutable.Seq[A]`. This poses no soundess problem. If `Y <: X`, a `Bar[Y]` is not a `Bar[X]`, but it is still a `Foo[X]`.

On the other hand, in example 2, the **`A[+_]` is a constraint on `A`**. Only types with a covariant type parameter may be parameters of Foo.  The code of `Foo` is likely to make use of that constraint, e.g an assignement of an `A[String]` to a `A[Any]` somewhere in the code of `Foo`.

Then allowing `Bar` to be instanciated with a not-covariant type would be unsound. The code inherited from `Foo` could still be called and assign the `A[String]` to the `A[Any]`, when `A` is no longer covariant.

A very similar soundness problem would happen anytime you allow lifting a constraint on a generic parameter. Suppose you have `Foo[X <: Ordered[X]]` (or `Foo[X : ordering]`) and you have a method `sort` in `Foo`. Suppose then that `Bar[X] extends Foo` is allowed. Maybe nothing in the code of `Bar` requires `X` to be ordered, but still, `sort` would be callable, and would certainly misbehave with items that cannot be ordered.

---

Regarding your question in the comment with Traversable[+Elem, +Col[+_]], and extending that into make a mutable class :

technically, yes, you can extend it and put some `var youCanMutateThat : Elem = _` inside. I guess this is not what you are looking for. But I suppose your plan is to allow using the extension with mutable Col, and I don't think you can do that, for the reason stated above. But then, why did you have the Col[+_] constraint in the first place?

Comment: makes sense, thanks. short follow-up question: the goal is to make a trait Traversable[+Elem, +Col[+_]] {
  def map[B](f : Elem => B) : Col[B]
}

is there any way to make a mutable subclass of this (like the mutable.Seq example)

Answer (score 2):

In Example 2 need to add covarince for A[_]

```
trait Bar[A[+_]] extends Foo[A]
```

Because **Foo** expect covariant type as parameter (+_ is a part of constraint for substituted type) and inherited type need guarantee that parameter will be covariant (limitation of substituted type).

In Example 1 you define that **Foo** (like container) is covariant by parameter and inherited container can be invariant (no limitation for substituted type)

more details in Martin-Löf type theory (**predicative parametric polymorphism**)